# Materialize links do not fit inside navigation

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav, materialize

**Problem:**

Fitting five links inside a navigation using Materialize CSS. Right now, three links fit and I can even add a fourth. But when I add five links in total, the last two break.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Materialize</title>
    <!-- CSS  -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="indigo" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-wrapper container">
                <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo"><i class="material-icons md-36">flight_takeoff</i> Logo</a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="material-icons left">add_circle</i> Registration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="material-icons left">account_circle</i> Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

**Desired output:**

To get all five links to fit inside the navigation on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `<a href="#">Contact` is missing the close tag.
Here's the updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Materialize</title>
    <!-- CSS  -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="indigo" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-wrapper container">
                <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo"><i class="material-icons md-36">flight_takeoff</i> Logo</a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li> <!-- Note the </a> closing tag -->
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="material-icons left">add_circle</i> Registration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="material-icons left">account_circle</i> Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```